# How do I do a projection query AND also retrieve multiple entries (from a given list of keys)

Tags: google-app-engine, python-3.x, google-cloud-datastore

This is what I have - why doesn't it work?
thing_keys is a list of datastore keys from the ThingsTable.

```
q = db.Query(ThingsTable, projection=['name', 'duration', 'cost','next_start_date', 'rate_ave_overall'])

courses = q.get(thing_keys)

_______
```

what does is work is when I use:
    courses = ThingsTable.get(thing_keys)

I wanted to do a projection for performance reasons - only need select fields.  This must be possible - Any ideas??

Comment: Note there are no tables. You should loop over q.run() and see what you get.

Answer (score 1):

Query get only return one entry and does not accept list of keys as parameter 
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass#Query_get

For the projection queries, make sure you have the required index. What do you mean by does not work? You get error? No result?

Comment: yes get error - but it does work when i don't put the projection in (see comment from Patrick)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you are trying to do is a mix of a get and a projection query. This is not possible using the datastore.

When you issue a query in the datastore, it uses indexes to find the list of keys for entities that satisfy that query, then look up those entities and return them. A projection query takes advantage of the fact that the indexes are made up of properties so it can avoid doing the second call to actually get the entities. However, when you already have the list of keys that you want, you can skip the indexes all together and just jump to the entities that you want.

By doing a direct get, you are actually getting a much better performance benefit by being able to avoid running the query over the indexes. If you are still worried about the performance of getting the entire entity, you should consider splitting the entity into the properties that you want most of the time and then the rest of the properties.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/storage_breakdown) is some more information on how entities are stored, if you are interested.